# Need help regarding this query

Tags: npm, installation

Facing issues while installing npm on cmd.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwuKh.png)

Comment: Please update the question with the error output in a text form. Please post that part of the log also, where a build of a module started and Python was required.

Comment: Hi milan can we sync up using google meet or somthing i need help and i am no software engineer?